# Graph Algorithm and Cycle Detection

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, contest-math, trees

In $O(|V|+|E|)$, we can detect whether a Directed Graph has a cycle or not. ---> True

In depth-first seach on DAG, there is no Back Edge. ---> True

With known Number of Edges, in $O(|V|)$ and not $O(|V|+|E|)$, we can detect whether a simple undirected Graph has a cycle or not. ---> True

Am I right about the above three questions about Graph Algorithm? I think all of them is True?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show the reasoning you used to get these answers?